# using XML as datasource in Yii framework

Tags: php, xml, yii, datasource

I am building a relatively simple application using the Yii framework for a college project and I need to use XML files as the data source rather than a DB. There is a tiny amount of data that will need to be persisted, and it won't change a whole lot so the complexity of a DB is unnecessary.

The XML files will store a few integers and some strings, this data will need to be read in and used by a controller class.

In terms of updating the data in the XML files, the user does not want to do that via the application, they will just open the file(s) itself and change the data manually when needed.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to go about this. Any info at all is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this extension: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cxmlmodel/

Comment: actually, scratch that, the people I'm building this for don't support sqlite. Thanks for your help though

Comment: Thanks marcovtwout, I'll check that out

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps worth considering using SQLite as this will create a database as a text file and perhaps simpler than using XML.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. Would it be easy then for a user to access this text file in order top update it manually, would they have to go through the application to do this?